# Change default page from index.php to index.html

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

Simple as the question. I want to change my website's default page from `index.php` to `index.html`. I don't know if my server (000webhost.com, while website is under development) uses Apache, but I've changed the `.htaccess` file, and added `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`. Still not working, though.

When the website loads, it loads randomwebsitename12345.com. If I add /index.html to the string, then the page loads fine, as it should. If I remove the .php file from my server, then the website loads index.html.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have 2 `DirectoryIndex`s? Look at the response header on request the server version might be in there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove `index.php` from the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I didn't have it there at first, then added it to see if it made any difference. Didn't, so I left it.

Comment: Fair enough. The other alternative is to just rename the `index.php` file to something other than `index`

Comment: Would still be good to know an alternative, but this'll do fine for now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rewrite rule to set **index.html** as your homepage :

Add this before other rules in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: Didn't work :(. Here's what is in my .htaccess file now:

RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

Comment: Remove the DirectoryIndex directive.